# React attribute vs props

Tags: reactjs

I'm having difficulty understanding the difference between attributes and props in React. Can you please provide a clear explanation with examples? I've already tried searching, but it hasn't helped me understand.

Comment: Consider studying HTML and JS before going for React. It looks like you're mixing the concepts of the framework with the concepts of one of those languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very similar, but an attribute is a "property" with a pre-defined "key" that you set on a native element, while a "prop" is a "property" that you set on a custom element (react functional or class component).

So, for example, if you have `<img src='foo.png'/>` then src is an attribute of the resulting DOM node.

But if you have `<MyComponent src='foo.png'/>` then src is a prop, which is passed to the custom component in its 'props'.

Answer (score 1):

`props` is an object containing the attributes defined when using the component.

```
// props contains hours/minutes/seconds when component is defined
const Clock = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>${props.hours}:${props.minutes}:${props.seconds}</div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  // and here the hours/minutes/seconds are defined, as attributes
  // when component is instantiated
  return (
    <Clock hours="15" minutes="43" seconds="29" />
  );
};
```

Since it's quite verbose to write `props.attribute` for all attributes, `props` is usually de-structured, e.g.

```
const Clock = ({ hours, minutes, seconds }) => {
  return (
    <div>${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are part of HTML markup. HTML is string/text that needs to be parsed and is then converted into an object tree, the DOM.

React props, JSX in general is Javascript **code** that creates a virtual-dom tree. *And then react does its thing and manipulates the real DOM.*

A major difference is for example, html attributes can only contain text, because that's all that html is. While properties, react props or (dom node) object properties can contain all kinds of data types.

It's like the difference between you and a picture of you. html is just a (very limited) description the DOM it represents.